# Vagrant permission with drupal using nfs

Tags: macos, drupal, drupal-7, vagrant, puphpet

I use vagrant as environment on OSX (made with [PUPHPET](https://puphpet.com/#vagrantfile-local)), and i use NFS for synced folder.
But i tried to install drupal on it, and the installation failed because of non writable file. 
Do you have any solution to change permission on NFS synced folder ? or should i use something different synced folder ?

```
Error
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
Exception: The directory <em class="placeholder">sites/default/files/config_UoG7KuH42rAreqqHW3qJvJP1SKbBL5Bsoln_xR2lZ4cXUkSW7M3ZCb-QyQi3vFJ8zr5pdnWuPQ/sync</em> could not be created or could not be made writable. To proceed with the installation, either create the directory and modify its permissions manually or ensure that the installer has the permissions to create it automatically. For more information, see the <a href="https://www.drupal.org/server-permissions">online handbook</a>. in drupal_install_config_directories() (line 508 of core/includes/install.inc).
```

Comment: Can you share your exact error message?

Comment: @SaeX Thank you for answer, I added the exact error message in my post !

Comment: just remove the nfs type for your synced folder and see if that works ?

Comment: i tried, it works but it's really really slow, something like 4-5s for loading a page... should i try rsync ? @FrédéricHenri

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the owner, group, and permissions of a synced folder using Vagrant...

```
config.vm.synced_folder "foo/", "/opt/foo",
  owner: "www-data",
  group: "www-data",
  mount_options: ["dmode=775", "fmode=664"]
```

The `www-data` user is the default user for both Apache and Nginx, so that's probably what you'll want to use. In the mount options, `dmode` sets permissions on directories while `fmode` sets permissions on files. Details for synced folders are in the [Vagrant docs](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/basic_usage.html).

If you don't want to edit the Vagrantfile directly, then I'm not sure if there's a relevant configuration option within PuPHPet that you can change.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the `www-data` user and group is by default on synced folder with puphpet... i tried a `ls -l` and this is what i get :
`drwxrwxr-x 25 www-data www-data 850 Dec 27 16:34 portfolio-drupal/`. Owner and group are correctly set, so why drupal can't write file ? @Patrick Lee

Comment: Can you change the Drupal configuration to write to a non-shared folder on the Vagrant box? Just to see if that works and narrow down the scope of the issue.

Comment: I tried this yesterday, and it works wells, but the folder is not shared and stay in the Vagrant box, but i would like to keep my synced folder... :/ @Patrick Lee

Comment: Right. I just wanted to verify that it's a Vagrant issue and not a Drupal issue.

Comment: I tried to run a WordPress installation, and it's always the same error, it don't have the write, and i can't modify them, or it's don't change anything... @Patrick Lee